# Issues Getting Highcharts Export Server Running Under iisnode

Tags: node.js, highcharts, iisnode

I am working on trying to set up the Highcharts export server under node.js using iisnode (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). It basically acts as a pipe between requests to IIS through to node. Great! Only, how do I "install" the highcharts export server so it is using iisnode? I did the instructions on how to install the highcharts-export node module but it is installed under (Windows) AppData\Roaming\npm. How to move or point iisnode to the export server?
This export server is run via the following once installed from npm:

```
highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1
```

So, to get this installed and used in IIS8 + iisnode
1) What is the right directory to install export server locally (on Windows the modules pulled in via npm go to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\nmp\ where  is the logged in user using npm to install the package)?
2) What is the iisnode configuration necessary for this?

I have the iisnode setup and running on our development box and all the examples work. My confusion lies partly with the utter lack of documentation for issnode. All the links I have found just repeat the items listed in the links from the issnode developer with no actual "here is how you take a node app that exists in npm and have it work in issnode." I don't necessarily need my hand held every step of the way. I am just seeing no list of steps to even follow.

Comment: from GitHub readme `The application can be used either as a CLI (Command Line Interface), as an HTTP server, or as a node.js module.` you can proxy requests to it, or you can call it programmatically. There is no reason to stick with the standalone http from cli.

Comment: Okay, this sounds like what I want but how? The iisnode docs are limited at best. I would imagine I would want this as a node module, right? The application URL would take the request for the exported image and process and return the image.

Comment: yes, check the module documentation it has all the details to use it as module. Also you will have to install it locally in your package and not globally.

Answer (score 0):

install node (if not already installed)
install iisnode (if not already installed => https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)
verify IIS has iisnode registered as a module
create a new Application Pool, set to "No Managed Code"
create a new empty web site
load the iisnode sample content into it, update the web.config 
verify you can hit it and it runs and can write it's logs
go to the IIS web site folder and run these npm commands
npm init /empty
npm install --save highcharts-export-server
npm install --save tmp

add file hcexport.js and reconfigure web.config

---

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var tmp = require('tmp');

const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    try {

        if (req.method !== 'POST') { throw "POST Only"; }
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
             body += data;
         });
        req.on('end', function () {
            if (body === '') { throw "Empty body"; }

            var tempFile = tmp.fileSync({discardDescriptor: true, postfix: ".svg", dir: process.cwd()}); 

            var input = JSON.parse(body);
            input.outfile = path.basename(tempFile.name);

            exporter.initPool();
            exporter.export(input, function (err, exres) {
                if (err) { throw "Export failed"; }

                var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), exres.filename);

                exporter.killPool();

                fs.readFile(filename, function(err, file) {
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml', 'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + exres.filename });
                    res.write(file.toString());
                    res.end();
                    tempFile.removeCallback();
                });             
            });

        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log({port: process.env.PORT, error: err});
        res.writeHead(409, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(err.message);
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Extend as needed to support the export types you plan to use.

The highcharts-export-server uses phantomjs internally and this can run away under some error conditions using up 100% of available CPU, if you see this you can kill it using:
Taskkill /IM phantomjs.exe /F

Comment: This works. Just keep in mind, that you have to set the type to `type: svg` or you will run into a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from saukender seems to work, however it seems that it always initializes a new pool of phantom workers every time.

If you already have node and issnode setup, another solution is to directly start the highcharts export server and not call the export function manually. This seems to provide a better performance, since it doesn't initialze the worker pool on every request.

```
// app.js
const highcharts = require("highcharts-export-server");

highcharts.initPool();
highcharts.startServer(process.env.PORT || 8012);
```

Don't forget to point your web.config to `app.js`.

I found these two resource quite useful during setup:

- https://www.galaco.me/node-js-on-windows-server-2012/
- https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html